# Mixed Content warning on Youtube Subscribe button over HTTPS

Tags: https, youtube, mixed-content

The Youtube subscribe button on our site has started to generate this mixed content type error just recently. It was working fine before.

Our site (https://data-miner.io) is fully on HTTPS. The URL for loading the Google script is also on HTTPS.

Even the example button off Google developer guide gives us the same error. Example code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers"></div>
```

And we get this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://data-miner.io/' was loaded over HTTPS,
but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?action_card=1&channelid=UCJsN_l9Nikc…res__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMHYgS7aNxNWsVBTJHTEp3IHdPl5g'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

[image]

Is this a Google bug? Why are they trying to load something over http. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**[UPDATE]**:  A week later and this is still broken. Google guys tried to fixed it and introduced yet another bug. Unbelivable! What kind of testing does this team do?  "VM7438 subscribe_embed?channelid=UCJsN_l9NikcAq9XikLD1nSg&action_card=1&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fsc…:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: __ytRIL is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same error, and it appears to be a Google bug. You can see the same error occurring on [YouTube's Configure a Button](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button) page.  I submitted a bug report to YouTube's issue tracker, which you can follow [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8668).

Comment: Hi Rommer, the last comment from a Google dev was yesterday stating "Thanks for the continued reports, everyone. We're still working on rolling out a fix for this." so it doesn't seem to fixed yet.  Starring that ticket I linked to above will alert you when the devs comment or resolve the issue.